# How to verify paypal reference transactions is enabled

Tags: paypal

Hi I'm setting up paypal pro for a client.  I need reference transactions to work as we would have to bill the customer each month and sometimes the amount may vary.

**Credit card payment**
The code flow has been tested with paypal sandbox and it completely works. But with the real account we get the following error.
"This transaction cannot be processed. Please contact PayPal Customer Service."

**Paypal Account Payment/Express Checkout**
It did not work with paypal sandbox too owing to reference transactions not being enabled.   i'm facing a similar situation with the paypal pro account too.  I get the error
"Merchant not enabled for reference transactions"

We sent a request to paypal asking them to enable reference transactions.  They replied back assuring they did but I still get the same error.  I even tried removing the current api signature and recreating a new one.  But I still get the same error.

Has anyone faced a similar situation ?

Is there any sure way of verifying if reference transactions is enabled?

If it is not, is there a way to enable it other than going through paypal's customer service (it's appalling) ?

Comment: Would you happen to have the full API response?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes it's easy.

Just try to make a payment with a billing agreement.

Just above the confirmation message on the PayPal website it will show:

> Use PayPal for future payments to XXX Inc. Payments will be made with
>   your default payment method unless you select a preferred payment
>   method. To make changes, go to My money in your Profile, and update
>   the My preapproved payments section.

If you don't see that message they're not enabled (or your request is wrong). But of course you can check in the sandbox to make sure the request is correct.